# Avoid using predefined css div while integration

Tags: css, html, integration

I have defined div in css file as follows:

```
div {
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:left;
  width:auto;
}

img {
  border:none;
}

ul {
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
```

This div was used in coding of entire html site. Now I want to integrate this html to different script but due to predefined div in css overrides the div tag of that script and appeared as broken page. 
Can anyone suggest how can I avoid this predefined div in my css for integrating with the different script. So, that the script coding will not use my predefined div from my css.

Comment: Add a class, don't globally style all `div`, `img` and `ul` elements

Comment: Can you define a class/id to the div?

Comment: you can user  jquery  to add classes to div  and can user diferently

Comment: ^ There's no need for `jQuery` here.

Answer (score 0):

you can always put more information infront the div, the div's where it's standing in.
Something like

```
container header div{
    height:auto; 
    float:left; 
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-align:left; 
    width:auto;
}
```

Or make it as a class style?
instead of "#" you will have to use the "." in css.

Hope this will works?